# Translate this monsterous query w/HABTM related data into a CakePHP find 

Tags: mysql, cakephp, join, has-and-belongs-to-many

It's late and I have written this monstrosity of a query to get related products based on a product I have already found.

I need to fetch the products in the same category (HABTM), the parent product, products with the same parent (siblings/neighbours), and products that are direct children of the current product (there is only one level of nesting). I have the product ID and its parent_id of the current product. If it could be possible to put conditions on the product as for `Product.published = 1` that would be great, but if it's going to make the query so big I can always check that after. Additionally, I need to exclude the current product.

```
SELECT `products`.*
FROM `products`, `categories_products`
WHERE
(
    (
        `categories_products`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
        AND `categories_products`.`category_id` IN (
            SELECT `category_id`
            FROM `categories_products`
            WHERE `categories_products`.`product_id` = '$product_id'
        )
    )
    OR `products`.`parent_id` = '$parent_id'
    OR `products`.`parent_id` = '$product_id'
    OR `products`.`id` = '$parent_id'
)
AND `product`.`id` <> '$product_id'

GROUP BY `products`.`id`
```

It might even be possible to optimize it a bit more, so far I have:

```
public function related($productData, $limit = 4) {

    $conditions = array(
        'OR' => array(array('Product.parent_id' => $productData['Product']['id'])), // Children of product),
        'Product.id <>' => $productData['Product']['id']
    );

    if(!empty($product['parent_id'])) {
        $conditions['OR'][] = array('Product.parent_id' => $productData['Product']['parent_id']); // Siblings
        $conditions['OR'][] = array('Product.id' => $productData['Product']['parent_id']); // Parent of product
    }

    return $this->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => $conditions,
        'contain' => array('Category'),
        'group' => 'Product.id',
        'limit' => $limit
    ));
}
```

Comment: Monsterous? It seems just a normal select... +1 for the marketing

Comment: @Márcio All about the banter :)

Comment: I hope these variables are embedded in the query for simplicity reasons?

Comment: You'll have to look into the "complex find queries" section of the manual for how to form sub-queries. Honestly though, after some point going through the Cake DAL just isn't worth it and you should simply carefully craft your own SQL and use `Model::query`.

Comment: Here is a real monster query: http://www.neilcrookes.com/2009/02/26/get-all-acl-permissions/

Comment: Before I attempt to provide an answer, it seems like the SQL query you provided does not return all of the data that you mention in your question. Are you asking for help converting your SQL into a find or are you asking for the data as in your text?  The reason I ask is because the description you give about what data you want sounds like an unstructured set -- meaning, I don't think you can get all of that with one query -- namely, the current product part. I can see Category - Parent Product - Product...but are you saying only show this structure where the current product exits?

Comment: @ScottHarwell I already know the current product exists, the variables I have for the query are the id and parent_id from that product.

Comment: I didn't word my question well.  What I am trying to ask is how do you expect the structure of the data returned based on your requirements. If you were looking for Categories -> Parents -> Record -> Children, then you have a structure to build a single query.  But your siblings requirements throws that off. If you are trying to return all that data in a single array, then creating a function, as you have, and merging multiple queries is probably what you will have to do.

Comment: @ScottHarwell Ideally I'd just like a normal Cake array of products, what I currently have returns what I need, are you saying the categories join is going to mess up that structure?

Comment: Some overlap, and exclusions, yet some appear counter-intuitive... Can you provide some samples of the data you are trying to include that show the correlation of elements you are trying to get all inclusive?

Comment: How can you have children of a product, if nesting is only 1 level? :S

Comment: @Ivo, it might be a 'top level' product, trying to cover all bases.

Comment: What does your current find return and what is the result you would expect? In other words, what's wrong with current find? (Which seems valid).

Comment: @Oldskool Nothing is wrong with the current find now, it's just missing the category join, although when I first wrote the question, it was missing a lot more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue came round again, and I figured it out 100%! Here was my finished code:

```
// Model
public function related($product, $limit = 9) {

    // Children of product
    $conditions = array(
        'OR' => array(array('Product.parent_id' => $product['Product']['id'])), // Children of product),
        'Product.id <>' => $product['Product']['id'],
        'Product.published' => 1
    );

    // Siblings and parent of product if applicable
    if (!empty($product['Product']['parent_id'])) {

        $conditions['OR'][] = array('Product.parent_id' => $product['Product']['parent_id']);
        $conditions['OR'][] = array('Product.id' => $product['Product']['parent_id']);
    }

    // Products in the same categories
    // Get category IDs in an array
    $categoryIds = Set::extract($product['Category'], '{n}.id');

    $conditionsSubQuery['category_id IN(?)'] = implode(',', $categoryIds);

    $db = $this->getDataSource();
    $subQuery = $db->buildStatement(
            array(
        'fields' => array('product_id'),
        'table' => 'categories_products',
        'joins' => array(),
        'alias' => 'c_p',
        'conditions' => $conditionsSubQuery,
        'order' => null,
        'group' => null,
        'limit' => null
            ), $this->CategoryProduct
    );
    $subQuery = 'Product.id IN (' . $subQuery . ') ';
    $subQueryExpression = $db->expression($subQuery);

    $conditions['OR'][] = $subQueryExpression;

    return $this->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => $conditions,
                'contain' => array('Category'),
                'group' => 'Product.id',
                'limit' => $limit
            ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use cake's [Complex Find Conditions syntax](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/view/74/Complex-Find-Conditions) (scroll down to Sub-queries secrion).

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I didn't think its the best approach to get "related" products from mysql, thats what search engines are for. especially your similar category approach is would doom to fail when dealing with big data.

After saying this much this is a a re-write of your current sql which would hopefully have you gain some performance.

```
SELECT * FROM products p
WHERE 
    p.published = 1 AND 
    p.id != $product_id AND
    (
        p.id IN 
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT(cp2.product_id) FROM categories_product cp1
                LEFT JOIN categories_product cp2 ON cp1.category_id = cp2.category_id
                WHERE cp1.product_id = $product_id
                UNION SELECT $parent_id
            )
        OR p.parent_id IN($parent_id, $product_id)
    )
;
```

I tried to get rid of unnecessary group by statement. Hope this helps.

P.S : There can be syntax errors since I wrote this in text editor.

Comment: The whole purpose of this question was to put the query into a CakePHP find, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would prevent the need of the recursive attempt to SELECT IN on the category.  Pre build that based on the one product in question and get all its distinct categories.  From that, get distinct products that match the category.  Now, you have a prequery of "CommonByCategory" that will ALREADY be a single instance of IDs.

Next, do a hard join to products again "OriginalProduct" based on the SPECIFIC ID you are trying to qualify against.  Since it will always exist and never change, we can use this as the pointer for the siblings to compare against, and also for a parent ID match (in case not null -- via the IFNULL() tests applied

Since each product will only be scanned ONCE and not return multiple entries due to the multiple category possibilities, no "GROUP BY" is required.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN 
      p.*
   from 
      products p
         left join 
            ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                    cp2.product_id
                 from
                    ( SELECT cp.Category_ID
                         from categories_products cp
                         where cp.product_id = '$product_id' ) JustCats
                     join categories_products cp2
                        ON JustCats.Category_ID = cp2.Category_ID ) as CommonByCategory
            ON p.ID = CommonByCategory.product_ID

         join products OriginalProduct
            ON OriginalProduct.ID = '$product_id'

   where
          p.id <> '$product_id'
      and ( IFNULL( CommonByCategory.Product_ID, -1) > 0
          OR p.id = IFNULL( OriginalProduct.Parent_ID, -1 )
          OR p.parent_id = OriginalProduct.id
```